# How can I distribute a precompiled, dynamic iOS framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dynamic, frameworks

I have a proprietary, dynamic iOS framework targeting iOS 8.0 above and using Swift. I want to distribute this in a precompiled form.

I tried building for release, copying over the framework to another project and adding it under the **Embedded Frameworks** section. However, I get the following error:

`ld: framework not found MyFramework`

If I remove my framework from the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section, my app compiles, but I cannot use the framework in my code.

How can I solve my problem?